# Creating a simple seeking media player with MediaElement in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player, mediaelement

I have also posted this on MSDN forums - i hope its not a problem.

I am basically trying to create a WPF based video player which allows you to seek within media. I'm trying to implement it using MediaTimeline (i know i can change the Position property, but i had other issues which i'll post in a separate question). XAML and code-behind are below.

Thanks for looking...

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Width="320" Height="240" Margin="4" LoadedBehavior="Manual"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var tl = new MediaTimeline(new Uri(@"c:\temp\!numa.wmv"));

            mediaElement.Clock = tl.CreateClock(true) as MediaClock;


            mediaElement.MediaOpened += (o, e) =>
            {
                slider.Maximum = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Seconds;
                mediaElement.Clock.Controller.Pause();
            };

            slider.ValueChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                mediaElement.Clock.Controller.Seek(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(slider.Value), TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas,
It does not work - moving the slider does not seek the video.

thanks
--oleg

Answer (score 2):

You need to set ScrubbingEnabled="True" on MediaElement to have it update during seeks.

Answer (score 1):

the MediaOpened event should actually be setting the maximum value to .TotalSeconds, and you should also set ScrubbingEnabled to True as jesperll pointed out.